# How could a viable transformation look like that does convert a product-name into a valid HTML id-attribute value?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, transform

There is a list of product data. Each product item has a `string`-type `name`-property.

How could a viable transformation look like that does convert a product-name into a valid  [HTML id-attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) value?.

Viable means that a transformation is build in a way that there should be almost no chance for generating identical id's from two different but similar constructed product names.

The naming of common products looks like this ...

1. `"2-inch leg extension"`
2. `"2' x 8' Overhead Garage Storage Rack"`
3. `"4 Drawer Base Cabinet 16-1/2"W x 35"H x 22-1/2"D"`
4. `"24" Long Tool Bar w/ Hooks  Accessory"`

Transformed validly the above list might look like that ...

1. `"z2-inchlegextension"`
2. `"z2x8OverheadGarageStorageRack"`
3. `"z4DrawerBaseCabinet16-12Wx35Hx22-12D"`
4. `"z24LongToolBarwHooksAccessory"`

One could consider providing a prefix (e.g. `"z"`) to the to be generated `id` in oder to make it a valid [HTML id-attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute).

I'm not familiar with replacement techniques that assure results which will be repeatable consistent.

How could a possible transformation approach look like?

Comment: Did you try anything? Share it with us. And what would be the actual output you are deserving?

Comment: I started to wright in plain JS But understood that there are many tings to consider and if anybody already done it will Save a lot of time. Or a Regex solution wich I dont familiar with. And yes I see what you mean "actual output" there are a lot of ways to handle it , Im editing my question . Thanks

Comment: @ManvelA. ... from your edited Q. it looks like you have to come up with a own replacement algorithm (describe it by own words or by a replacement table) since you are the one that might know all possible product names best. You then might ask for support or approaches of how to put this into working  code.

Comment: I hited Ctrl Enter until i finished to and it published Take a look i think now is better. And yes you are right I think i need to wright it. In any way The answere of @ControlAltDel Helped me alot .

Comment: @PeterSeliger I understand your point. I could have should have done what you say. However with respect, I disagree. My answer may be trivial, but it is also relatively canonical, whereas de-duping IDs is much less canonical. So what I'm saying is that if you do two Q/A's instead of 1, you get the canonical solution that everyone can see, plus the different approaches to de-duping IDs that people can also find. This way, you get a hodge-podge. I get what you are saying - I do! And I cannot and won't fight SO "aristrocracy". I'm just trying to make a point on how best to use SO, IMO.

Comment: Linking to some documentation would help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id The specs: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this-

```js
const data = [
  "2-inch leg extension",
  "2' x 8' Overhead Garage Storage Rack",
  "4 Drawer Base Cabinet 16-1/2\"W x 35\"H x 22-1/2\"D",
  "24\" Long Tool Bar w/ Hooks  Accessory"
];

const res = data.map(str => str.replace(/[^a-z\d\-_]/ig, ''));

console.log(res);
```

If you need any prefix with the ID then add it like-

```
const prefix = 'Z';
const res = data.map(str => prefix + str.replace(/[^a-z\d\-_]/ig, ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer that fulfills your requirement:

```
string.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g, "");
```

If there are no letter characters this will result in an empty string. But since IDs need to start with letters anyway, you need special handling for cases where your product names have no letters in them

Comment: I like it. But i figured out that in this way there will be repeated ids when i have different sizes of the same product . Thank you for your time. As Sajeeb Ahamed suggested im editing the question.

Comment: @ManvelA. The question you asked was how to convert a string into a valid id. I answered that question, and now you have changed the question. This is not fair to me. You should mark my answer of this question as correct, and post another question on SO

Comment: @ControlAltDel ... you also could have just waited until the OP was going to change the Q in order to be more precise about the requirements. Other people were asking the OP to do so. You also could have joined the process of clarifying the OP's real problem. If I had chosen to start with a very quick trivial answer to unclear requirements (the OP was downvoted because of that) I would not negotiate about votes and blame the OP for unfair behavior. I would actively ask the OP for requirements and adjust my answer accordingly.

Comment: @PeterSeliger My apologizes

Answer (score 0):

The following approach creates configurable identifiers.

It also preserves as much information of a given product name as possible in order to prevent the accidental creation of identifier duplicates.

It does so by translating the string patterns of technical measures, units and terms as much as it could be anticipated from the examples provided by the OP.

```js
const productNameList = [
  "2-inch leg extension",
  "2' x 8' Overhead Garage Storage Rack",
  '4 Drawer Base Cabinet 16-1/2"W x 35"H x 22-1/2"D',
  '24" Long Tool Bar w/ Hooks  Accessory'
];

function createIdentifier(str) {
  const config = this;

  const prefix = config.prefix || '_';
  const separator = config.separator || '';

  const id = [prefix, str

    // replace foot symbol that follows immediately after a digit
    .replace((/([\d])'/g), `$1${ separator }Ft`)

    // replace inch symbol (double quote character)
    .replace((/"/g), `${ separator }In${ separator }`)

    // replace times character enclosed by word boundaries
    .replace((/\bx\b/g), 'Times')

    // replace digit connector, a minus symbol enclosed by digits
    .replace((/([\d])-([\d])/g), `$1${ separator }And${ separator }$2`)

    // replace division symbol that is enclosed by digits
    .replace((/([\d])\/([\d])/g), `$1${ separator }By${ separator }$2`)

    // uppercase any character that follows a word boundary
    .replace((/\b([\w])/g), ([$1]) => $1.toUpperCase())

     // replace/delete all non word characters.
    .replace((/[\W]+/g), separator)

  ].join('');

  return ((separator && id.toLowerCase()) || id);
}


console.log(
  productNameList,
  ' => HTML id attribute => ',
  productNameList.map(createIdentifier, { prefix: 'pid_' })
);

console.log(
  productNameList,
  ' => HTML id attribute (long) => ',
  productNameList.map(createIdentifier, { prefix: 'pid_', separator: '-' })
);

console.log(
  productNameList,
  ' => valid JS variable name => ',
  productNameList.map(createIdentifier)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is a great piece of code and I think it will be more useful for people who will find this question because it is very customizable, I thank you for your patience and good behavior.